# iOS Swift: How to store the index of all duplicate values in array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Let's take for example I have this array:

```
let dates = ["01/02/16", "02/02/16", "03/02/16", "01/02/16", "02/02/16"]
```

What I like to do is store each `String` date in a dictionary as the key, and for each key that repeats, I like to store the index of it as an array, and associate it with the duplicate key.

For example, `01/02/16` occurs at index `0` and `3`. `02/02/16` occurs at index `1` and `4`.

I like to have a dictionary that is something like this:

```
[ "01/02/16": [0, 3], "02/02/16": [2, 4], "03/02/16": [1] ]
```

I know how to keep track of how many duplicate entries there are like this:

```
let dates = ["01/02/16", "01/02/16", "02/02/16", "03/02/16"]

var dateCounts:[String:Int] = [:]

for date in dates
{
    dateCounts[date] = (dateCounts[date] ?? 0) + 1

}

for (key, value) in dateCounts
{
    print("\(key) occurs \(value) time/s")
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to keep track of the duplicate indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var duplicatedDict : [String:[Int]] = [:]
    let dates = ["01/02/16", "01/02/16", "02/02/16", "03/02/16"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        for (index,dateString) in dates.enumerated() {
            if(duplicatedDict[dateString] == nil){
                duplicatedDict[dateString] = [index]
            }else{
                duplicatedDict[dateString]?.append(index)
            }
        }

        debugPrint(duplicatedDict)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Console Log output

> ["02/02/16": [2], "01/02/16": [0, 1], "03/02/16": [3]]

Hope this helps

Comment: @Reinier..another question, since a Dictionary has no sense of "order"...how can I append just the array of indices into another array that is ordered based on the ordering of the `dates` array?....For example something like `[ [0,1], [2], [3] ]` where it corresponds to the ordering originally in `dates` array....or even just eliminate the `[ String: [Int] ]` pairing all together and have just `[ [Int] ]`?

Comment: You can order your keys and return the values of your keys ordered, but first you need to convert to Date in order to return right order

Comment: @sorry I'm a beginner at this..I'm not sure what you mean, can you attach an example below your answer?

Comment: @Pangu You can add another question, this is better because others can post their solutions, and maybe I learn also from that

Comment: @Pangu if you post another question please let me know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537650/ios-swift-track-and-store-indices-of-all-duplicate-values-in-an-array