# iOS Swift: Track and store indices of all duplicate values in an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I recently asked this question: [iOS Swift: How to store the index of all duplicate values in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537202/ios-swift-how-to-store-the-index-of-all-duplicate-values-in-array)

I was provided with the exact answer to my question, but I found that I could not use it to implement what I need in my code.

I'm trying to store all the indices of any duplicate values of a `Date` array and store in another array `[ [Int] ]`.

For example, here's my `Date` array:

```
let dates = [2016-01-02 08:00:00 +0000, 2016-01-02 08:00:00 +0000,
             2016-02-02 08:00:00 +0000, 2016-03-02 08:00:00 +0000, 
             2016-05-01 08:00:00 +0000, 2016-05-01 08:00:00 +0000]
```

What I am trying to do, similar to my previous question is to store all the indices of all repeated `Date` values into a separate array.

For example, the following array would contain:

```
repeatedIndices = [ [0, 1], [2], [3], [4, 5] ]
```

where indices `0` and `1` contains the repeated date `2016-01-02 08:00:00 +0000` and indices `4` and `5` contains the repeated date `2016-05-01 08:00:00 +0000`.

My previous question had an answer that provided it in a `[ String: [Int] ]`, and being a beginner, I don't know how to manipulate it to work with my code since the dictionary is **unordered** and I need an **ordered** array.

Please mark as duplicate if necessary, but I didn't want to edit the question and un-mark the answer as it would be unfair.

Thank you.

Comment: check my updated answer, using your new needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `[Date:[Int]]` dictionary with your example values,

```
var duplicatedDict : [Date:[Int]] = [:]

for (index,date) in datesArray.enumerated() {
            if(duplicatedDict[date] == nil)
            {
                duplicatedDict[date] = [index]
            }else
            {
                duplicatedDict[date]?.append(index)
            }
        }

debugPrint(duplicatedDict)
```

***So far, so good we have this as result in Console***

> [2016-02-02 08:00:00 +0000: [2], 2016-05-01 08:00:00 +0000: [5, 6], 2016-03-02 08:00:00 +0000: [3, 4], 2016-01-02 08:00:00 +0000: [0, 1]]

Then we need to cycle over the sorted dictionary keys and add to array the values in each key array

```
func returnValuesOrdered() ->[[Int]]{

        var result : [[Int]] = []

        for key in duplicatedDict.keys.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})
        {
            result.append(duplicatedDict[key]!)
        }

        debugPrint(result)
        return result
    }
```

***result in Console***

> [[0, 1], [2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

Hope this helps you